# google tink got "referenceerror: self is not defined" when using in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, tink

We are trying to use google tink and below is a sample that how we use it.

```
    const tinkLoader = () => import("tink-crypto");
    
    tinkLoader().then((tink) => {
      tink.hybrid.register();
      const keyset = stringToUint8Array(atob(resource_response.data.encoded_key));
      tink.binary
        .deserializeNoSecretKeyset(keyset)
        .getPrimitive(tink.hybrid.HybridEncrypt)
        .then((hybridEncrypt) => {
          //do some thing
        });
    });
```

This is the error message:

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
at internal/proto.ts:85:23
at node_modules/tink-crypto/bundles/tink-crypto.umd.js:2:68
at Object. (node_modules/tink-crypto/bundles/tink-crypto.umd.js:5:2)
```

We used npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/tink-crypto so I thought google tink supports backend JS. But according to this message, somewhere in the code has reference to self which is a variable of Window class and Window is not existing in Nodejs. Our Node is V12.

Can anyone please help me about this? It's really hard to find any doc online about JS tink.

Thanks!

Comment: I would say, since it's using `crypto.subtle` that it's definitely browser only - even though crypto.subtle was added in node version 15, that won't help since self is still undefined

Comment: I do wonder though if there were some way in node15+, e.g. `global.self = self` before importing tink-crypto - since `self` is only ever used for `self.crypto.subtle` - though you'd also have to import crypto and add global.crypto = crypto.webCrypto